# Why isn't my custom post type using my custom template?

Tags: wordpress, templates, custom-post-type

I've created a custom post type and I'm trying to use a custom template for showing the content.

My template file is named `single-event.php` *<-- The error was here*

My custom post type code is:

```
function create_post_type() {
  $args = array(
    'labels' => array(
      'name' => __( 'Événement' ),
      'singular_name' => __( 'Événement' ),
      'add_new' => __('Nouvel Événement')
    ),
    'public' => true,
    'has_archive' => true,
    'taxonomies' => array('event_data'),
    'menu_position' => 5,
    'supports' => array( 'title', 'editor', 'thumbnail', 'excerpt' ),
    'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'event')
  );

  register_post_type( 'event',$args);
}
```

My custom template looks like this:

```
<?php get_header(); ?>

  <div  id="event" class="full-width-container single-post">
    TEEEEEEEST
  </div>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Opening a custom post in my browser, the url is:

```
http://my.site.no/?event=my-custom-post-title
```

But why is it using `single.php` and not `single-event.php`? What am I missing?

Comment: My first inclincation is that their is a problem loading single-event.php, like a permissions issue, or invalid code.  Could be something as simple as missing "<?php" from the start of the file.

Comment: It's not a code issue (see updated Q with template code) and there is no reason why it should be a permission problem. Everything else works.

Comment: Was right though, wasn't I.  It was a problem loading single-event.php ;)

Glad you worked it out, these things are usually something annoyingly small like that!

Comment: For sure! I forgot to look at the file name - even though I changed it 3 times (but I only cahnged the name after 'single-' and didn't see the spelling error). This it what they mean by being blind on your own code :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally found my mistake - two actually.

I had a category called `event` - that was my first mistake (I think).
My second mistake was that my filename was `singe-event.php` <-- missing the `l`

And that's how you spend 5 hours debugging and reading up on Custom Templates combined with Custom Post Types....

Answer (score 0):

Wordpress need sometimes refresh permalink with custom posts.
You should try to activate permalink and try again !

Hope it will work for you..

And just add rewrite parameter  and try url example.com/event

```
function create_post_type() {
$args = array(
'labels' => array(
  'name' => __( 'Événement' ),
  'singular_name' => __( 'Événement' ),
  'add_new' => __('Nouvel Événement')
),
'public' => true,
'has_archive' => true,
'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'event' ), //Add this parameter
'taxonomies' => array('event_data'),
'menu_position' => 5,
'supports' => array( 'title', 'editor', 'thumbnail', 'excerpt' ),
'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'event')
);
```

Comment: Betrand, I already have that line in the code if you look (bottom line). PS. Don't you have enough points to edit your answer?

Comment: Sorry I'm new on stackoverflow ... so i'm not sure how to best practice ;)

Comment: No worries, you'll get the hang of it :) You can read more about how to use Stackoverflow here: http://stackoverflow.com/help